# How to convert this method in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've already done this method in django. But I wanna convert this in django-rest-framework. I'm not how to do this can any one help me regarding this . I want to know how to build the serializers and views for this.
At the same time how to send additional data in this itself
sorry the code being dirty
thank you in advance...

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
ADDCHKS_ID=models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True, null=True)
is_excutive=models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True, null=True)

class ExcutiveRegistration(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
'''Personal Details'''
First_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True ,blank=True)
Last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True ,blank=True)
DOB = models.DateField(max_length=100,null=True ,blank=True)
Fathers_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True ,blank=True)
Contact_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=10,null=True ,blank=True)
Alt_Contact_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=10,null=True ,blank=True)
# Profile_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, verbose_name="")
'''Current Addresss'''
Pin_code_c = models.IntegerField(max_length=6,null=True ,blank=True)
State_c = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True ,blank=True)
District_c = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True ,blank=True)
Taluk_c = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True ,blank=True)
Location_c = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True ,blank=True)
House_no_c = models.IntegerField(max_length=4,null=True ,blank=True)
Street_c = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True ,blank=True)
'''Permanent Address'''
Pin_code_p = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, null=True,blank=True)
State_p = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True,blank=True)
District_p = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True,blank=True)
Taluk_p = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True,blank=True)
Location_p = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True,blank=True)
House_no_p = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, null=True,blank=True)
Street_p = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True,blank=True)
'''Reference'''
Family_reference_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True,blank=True)
Family_reference_conatact_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True,blank=True)
Neighbour_reference_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True,blank=True)
Neighbour_reference_contact = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True,blank=True)
'''Document Proof'''
ID_Proof_Document_Type=models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                        choices=ID_CHOICES,
                                        default="Voter",
                                        null=True,
                                        blank=True)
# ID_Proof_Document= models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, verbose_name="")
'''Bank Details'''
# Account_Name=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
# Bank_name=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
# Account_Number=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
# IFSC_Code=models.IntegerField(max_length=15, null=True)
'''Area Covered'''
Work_State=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True ,blank=True)
Work_covering_district=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True ,blank=True)
Working_location=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True ,blank=True)
Status=models.CharField(max_length=50,
                            choices=Status_,
                            default='No Action',
                            null=True
                            ,blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.First_name)



class ExcutiveRegistrationPincode(models.Model):
ExcutiveRegistration=models.ForeignKey(ExcutiveRegistration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Covering_Pincode=models.IntegerField(max_length=6)
```

views.py

```
class ExcutiveHomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
context_object_name = 'customers'
template_name = 'accounts/excutive/excutive_home_page.html'

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pincodes = [
        e.Covering_Pincode
        for e in ExcutiveRegistrationPincode.objects.filter(
            ExcutiveRegistration__user=self.request.user
        ).only('Covering_Pincode')
    ]
    return Customer.objects.filter(Pincode__in=pincodes,Status='Avaiable')
```

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
class Excutivehomepagess(generics.ListAPIView):


model=Customer
serializer_class=CustomerSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    pincodes = [
        e.Covering_Pincode
        for e in ExcutiveRegistrationPincode.objects.filter(
            ExcutiveRegistration__user=self.request.user.id
        ).only('Covering_Pincode')
    ]
    
    return Customer.objects.filter(Pincode__in=pincodes, Status='Avaiable')
```

serializers.py

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model= Customer
    fields= '__all__'
```